# Une autre démission

Tags: discussion, moderation

J'ai beaucoup appris lors de l'élan de création initial du site et je tiens à remercier tout ceux qui ont participé à le construire en combinant leur expertise sur la langue française.

Ces derniers temps, je ne contribue presque plus et ai perdu tout intérêt à rester, forcé d'une part de constater que la qualité du contenu et de son évaluation par le vote sont à la baisse et d'autre part que la direction que prend l'entreprise hôte, ainsi que ses actes et décisions récentes, vont trop souvent à l'encontre des intérêts de nos communautés sur *Stack Exchange*.

Je démissionne donc de mon poste de modérateur et laisse ceux qui le souhaiteraient prendre le relais.

---

**Gist:** I'm stepping down as a moderator. Is our expert community dying out? Have SO's interests become misaligned with our own?

---

**Translation:**

I learned a lot during the rush of the site's initial launch, and I have to thank everyone who took part in building it up through their combined expertise in the French language.

For the last while, I've barely contributed anymore and have lost all interest in staying. On one front, it's been impossible not to see that the quality of the content and its evaluation through the voting system are declining, while on the other front, the company's direction, as well as its recent actions and decisions, have too often gone against the interests of our communities on Stack Exchange.

Therefore I'm resigning from my role as moderator and leaving it to whoever wishes to take the reins.

Answer (score 9):

Merci Stéphane pour tout le travail et le bel effort. Tu as su mieux que quiconque ici sentir lorsque je perdais patience et d'un rappel à l'ordre cordial, subtil, presque attentionné, me remettre sur les rails sans qu'il n'y ait d'esbrouffe. Je ne puis parler pour les autres, mais je suppose que tu possédais ce genre de sensibilité qui te permettait de conserver l'ordre en percevant les minuscules perturbations, et par des actions le plus souvent quasi-insensibles réaligner le tir en tout respect pour les usagers.

C'est une grande perte, mais je comprends la décision.

Bonne continuation !

Comment: Merci et bon courage à tout le monde pour la suite !

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for all your time and input.

> Is our expert community dying out?

Yes, I think "our expert community is dying out"<sup>1</sup>.

> Have SO's interests become misaligned with our own?

Yes, SO's interests have become "misaligned with our own"<sup>2</sup>.

**But**, and as I said elsewhere, the community on [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) has changed a lot from what it used to be when it started just over 8 years ago, I find [community moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) is no longer working. What I can't answer is whether the community has changed because of the overall changes brought about by SO or because of a problem specific to this community.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>. [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/176183)

<sup>2</sup>. [Joel left, and SE as we know it is dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339074/176183)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Je fais miens les propos des autres réponses et je te remercie pour tout le travail ! Je me souviens avoir été témoin je crois entre autres de moments où des pans entiers de commentaires ont sauté ou ont été transformés en salles éphémères, ce que j'ai particulièrement apprécié ! D'autre part j'ai particulièrement aimé lire, par exemple, ces contenus où tu tentais de systématiser la présentation de certains éléments de grammaire, ce qui est particulièrement utile si exigeant.

Le réseau connaît des ratés. La judiciarisation du différend empêche d'aller au fond des choses avec les moyens du bord et le fossé n'a cessé de s'élargir semble-t-il parce qu'on a fait la sourde oreille et qu'on s'est enfargé dans les fleurs du tapis ; puis la majorité des utilisateurs ne saura rien pendant longtemps tandis qu'un flot de bêtises coule sur le site Meta et que les enjeux communautaires ont été occultés.

Le site *French Language* bien, quoi dire. Dernièrement, c'est parfois très approximatif et on répond trop vite et dans certains cas on manque de rigueur et on étaye pas vraiment ce qui force le lecteur à faire la recherche lui-même. Puis on sanctionne peu les contenus douteux. Ça donne l'impression d'un haut niveau d'incertitude du lectorat par rapport à la langue, qu'il ne posséderait pas probablement, que ce soit parce que ce n'est pas sa langue ou parce qu'on ne la maîtrise pas ou que l'on ne se donne pas la peine de vérifier ou de faire une recherche. Les contributeurs doivent exiger davantage d'eux-mêmes à mon avis et revenir au sujet du site et cesser de divaguer et de broder. D'où que c'est la fin de cette réponse. Merci !